# python non-daemonic thread inside non-daemonic process not working

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

A simple non daemonic python thread shown below works as expected:

```
import threading
import time

def printBar():
    for i in range(5):
        print "Bar"
        time.sleep(1)

barThread = threading.Thread(target=printBar)
barThread.daemon = False
barThread.start()
time.sleep(2.5)
print "Main thread exits"
```

output:

```
Bar
Bar
Bar
Main thread exits
Bar
Bar
```

But, if we put the thread inside a child process of the main process, the thread exits along with the process, even when it is set to be non-daemonic. Is there a workaround to keep the thread alive when the parent process exits?
Sample code:

```
import threading
import time
import multiprocessing

def Foo():
    def printBar():
        for i in range(5):
            print "Bar"
            time.sleep(1)

    barThread = threading.Thread(target=printBar)
    barThread.daemon = False
    barThread.start()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    print "Foo process exits"

fooProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=Foo)
fooProcess.daemon = False
fooProcess.start()
print "Main process Exits"
```

Obtained output:

```
Main process Exits
Bar
Bar
Bar
Foo process exits
```

Desired output:

```
Main process Exits
Bar
Bar
Bar
Foo process exits
Bar
Bar
```

**Answer to @moe-a 's comment below ( I don't have enough reputation to comment :( ):**

That is a good question. I could call thread.join at the end of the process to wait for the thread to be done. But I would prefer not to, if possible, so that even if the process were to crash at some other point before reaching it's end, the thread would continue to operate as you would expect for a non-daemonic thread.

Comment: Why do you wanna exit the process before the thread is done?